# Why am I getting a syntax error when trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transaction, rollback

I would like to use a transaction to call upon a stored procedure on many rows. If it fails on a single row, I want to roll back everything. Otherwise I want to commit.

I have the following so far but it throws the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near  'DECLARE val1 INT DEFAULT 0; DECLARE check INT DEFAULT 1;
>   DECLARE done BOOL DEFAU' at line 3

```
 DELIMITER \\
 BEGIN

 DECLARE val1 INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE check INT DEFAULT 1; 
 DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE e INT DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Table1.col1 FROM Table1 WHERE Table.col2 = (SELECT col1 FROM Table2 WHERE col3 = 'xxx');

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

 START TRANSACTION;

 OPEN cursor1;

 my_loop:
 LOOP

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO val1;
    IF done THEN
            LEAVE my_loop;
    ELSE
            storedProcedure1(val1,100,e);
            IF SELECT e = 0 THEN
                    ROLLBACK;
                    SET check = 0;
                    LEAVE my_loop;
            END IF;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  IF check = 1 THEN
       COMMIT;
  END IF;
  END;
```

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Missing the `END`? Not setting the delimiter to something other than the semicolon?

Comment: I have those; just forgot to add them here. Have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a stored procedure, you have to use the `CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax, see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html). You can't use procedural language constructs such as `DECLARE` in normal SQL.

Also, you have to use the special delimiter you've declared after the final `END`, so the last line will be `END\\`. (And after that, don't forget to set `DELIMITER` back to `;`, or you'll struggle.)

(There could be other problems as well, these are just two I spotted right away.)

Answer (score 0):

You missed the CREATE PROCEDURE PART, doing a quick refactor the script should be written like this...

```
DELIMITER \\
CREATE PROCEDURE your_sp_name()
BEGIN

DECLARE val1 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE check INT DEFAULT 1; 
DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE e INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Table1.col1 FROM Table1 WHERE table_name.col2 IN (SELECT col1 FROM Table2 WHERE col3 = 'xxx');

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

START TRANSACTION;

OPEN cursor1;

my_loop:
LOOP

FETCH cursor1 INTO val1;
IF done THEN
   LEAVE my_loop;
ELSE
   CALL storedProcedure1(val1,100,e);
   IF e = 0 THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        SET check = 0;
        LEAVE my_loop;
   END IF;
END IF;
END LOOP;

IF check = 1 THEN
    COMMIT;
END IF;

CLOSE cursor1;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```